# How do I print the characters on the same line?

Tags: python, cs50

I'm trying to print the cipher text on the same line. When I run the program now all the characters get printed on to the next line. How do I do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cs50
import sys

def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('caesar.py k')
        exit(1)

    k = int(sys.argv[1])

    print('plaintext: ', end = '')

    s = cs50.get_string()

    print('ciphertext: ', end = '')

    for i in range(len(s)):

        c = s[i]

        if str.isupper(c):
            cipher = (((ord(c) - 65) + k) % 26) + 65
            print(chr(cipher))
        elif str.islower(c):
            cipher = (((ord(c)- 97) + k) % 26) + 97
            print(chr(cipher))
        else:
            print(chr(c))

    exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from

```
c - chr(65)
```

If you look at the type of `chr(65)` it's actually a string.

```
>>> type(chr(65))
str
```

The TypeError you're getting is just telling you that you can't subtract a string from another string.

You might want to look at using `ord` instead which returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of a character.

Furthermore

```
for i in range(len(s)):

    c = s[i]
```

Is a python anti-pattern and can be simplified wth just

```
for c in s:
    print(c)   # c is your character
```

Since s is an iterable

Comment: You missed one thing - answer the question: "How do I print the characters on the same line?" :D

Answer (score 1):

No worries, I answered this. I added a `end = ''` at the end of the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jack Evans is the best style to go.  However, for your interest I've made some modifications to help answer your question (hopefully):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cs50
import sys

def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('caesar.py k')
        exit(1)

    k = int(sys.argv[1])

    print('plaintext: ', end = '')
    s = cs50.get_string()
    print(s)

    print('ciphertext: ', end = '')

    for i in range(len(s)):

        c = s[i]

        if str.isupper(c):
            cipher = (((ord(c) - 65) + k) % 26) + 65
            print(chr(cipher), end= '')
        elif str.islower(c):
            cipher = (((ord(c)- 97) + k) % 26) + 97
            print(chr(cipher), end= '')
        else:
            print(chr(c), end= '')        
    print()
    exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the example output if someone executed the script as:

```
./name_of_file 3
```

with the string being:

```
howdy
```

The result would be:

```
plaintext: howdy
ciphertext: krzgb
```

To answer you question directly, to have the print cipher characters print on the same line just change:

```
print(chr(cipher))
```

to

```
print(chr(cipher), end= '')
```

In Python, using print() without specifying how print should end it will automatically end with a newline.  As you can see in the version I provided, you can use this idea to easily incorporate newlines.

Cheers